# How to use html accept attribute in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

[image]How to use html accept attribute in visualforce(vf), here the accept attribute will accept only the particular extension when we click choose file button.i have pasted the code.

Html code:

```
<input type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls," name="myfile"/>
```

visualforce(vf) code: I have tried like this, its not working please suggest me.

```
  <apex:inputFile accept=".xlsx,.xls," value="{!file.versionData}" fileName="{!file.pathOnClient}" styleClass="slds-button--brand"  onchange="showbutton()" />
```

Thanks.

here if i click choose file button it should show only excel files in the directory,nothing should be visible other than that- this is my requirement.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"?

Comment: yes its not working

Comment: "It's not working" is too vague. Does it crash your computer? Display an error message? Log out of Salesforce? How are we supposed to know how to help you?

Comment: Not showing any error,that accept attribute is not running in vf page

Comment: Could you post more of the vf page please?

Comment: Again... what do you mean "is not running"? What behavior are you expecting, and what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: i have added image on the post,plz review once

Comment: I've just built a basic page and controller where the controller accepts a Blob `public Blob myFile { get; set; }` and uses the following Visualforce code `<apex:inputFile value="{!myFile}" accept=".xlsx,.xls" />` and it works fine?

Answer (score 2):

The "accept" attribute is a suggestion to the browser on how to behave. This behavior is different for all major browsers.

## Chrome

Displays "Custom Files" and "All Files", where "Custom Files" is selected by default.

## Firefox

Displays "All Files", "All Supported Files (.xls, .xlsx)", ".xls", and ".xlsx", with "All Supported Files (.xls, .xlsx)" selected by default.

## Edge (Internet Explorer)

Displays "All Files (*)", "*.gif", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.htm", "*.html", "*.xls", and "*.xlsx", with "All Files (*)" selected by default.

---

As you can see, the behavior depends on the browser, with Chrome and Firefox going with the standards, and Internet Explorer ignoring this particular standard.

You can't force the browser to literally only show specified file types, however, as all browsers allow an override to select any file. This might be because, for example, the user decides to call their XLS files ".spreadsheet" or some other non-standard convention.

In summary, accept is working as well as can be expected given the current state of affairs. You always need to validate your user input if you're expecting a certain type of file (e.g. by checking the first few bytes of data for a magic string, checking the ContentType attribute of the file, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!file.versionData}" accept=".xlsx,.xls" fileName="{!file.pathOnClient}" styleClass="slds-button--brand"  onchange="showbutton()" />
```

Comment: how to use this in custom settings?